# GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory Android 10+ upgrade issue: trying to get the Bitmap created from external app (OfficeLens) into my app

Tags: android, image, bitmap, external

I'm pretty new to the Android world, and I'm facing problems with an app written in Xamarin Android Mono environment.

I need to upgrade Android Target API at least to 29 (better 30), and I stuck at "scoped storage" change.
Although I was able to manage my own pictures taken by the camera (introducing the FileProvider), I still have problem with external images taken by the app Microsoft Office Lens (stored in public folder Pictures/Office Lens).

Summarizing, I use to call OfficeLens by an intent from my app:

```
StartActivity(Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage("com.microsoft.office.officelens"))
```

checking for new files with the "deprecated" GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory, that is still working for my porpouse (such as read the list of Office Lens file in order to find new ones):

```
var TmpDir = new File(Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryPictures), "Office Lens");
```

Read the NewFiles saving the paths into a list:

```
var LstFilesNew = new List<string>();
... 
foreach (var I in TmpDir.ListFiles())
{
  if (I.IsFile == true)
  {
    LstFilesNew.Add(I.Path);
  }
 }
```

Whether before simply used to call this function passing the FilePath to get the BitMap:

```
public static Bitmap LoadBitmap(this string fileName)
{
  var options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

  options.InJustDecodeBounds = false;

  return BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(fileName, options);
}
```

With scoped storage I'm trying to get the URI, from the URI to get the Bitmap via MediaStore:

```
    foreach (var FileNew in LstFilesNew)
    {
      if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Q)
        {
          ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
          contentValues.Put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DisplayName, FileNew);
          contentValues.Put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MimeType, "image/jpg");
          contentValues.Put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RelativePath, Environment.DirectoryPictures);
          Uri imageUri = Application.Context.ContentResolver.Insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri, contentValues);

          fos = Application.Context.ContentResolver.OpenOutputStream(imageUri); 
          Android.Graphics.Bitmap finalBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.GetBitmap(Application.Context.ContentResolver, imageUri);
          finalBitmap.Compress(Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, fos);
          fos.Close();
        }
    }
```

My URI seems to be ok ("content://media/external/images/media/1563") but I obtain a "finalBitmap" null after calling "MediaStore.Images.Media.GetBitmap".

I guess I'm completely wrong in my approach, but I spent some days to trying and googling without any result.

Any helps about how to get a bitmap from pictures taken by a third party application in Pictures/"xxx" it'll be really appreciated.

Thank you in advance, cheers

Comment: Your code to get an uri can not work. You use insert() to get an uri. Then you use that uri to get a bitmap and then you compress that bitmap to that same uri again. That sequence makes no sense. And before that you got null instead of a bitmap.

Comment: `Whether before simply used to call this function passing the FilePath to get the BitMap` Ok. And if you use it on an Android 11 device? Does it work then? You did not tell us. And on an Android 10 device? I think that if you can list those files you can load them too. But maybe not...

Comment: `public static Bitmap LoadBitmap(this string fileName)` Only a file name will not do. `public static Bitmap LoadBitmap(string path)`

Comment: IIf you want to use the MediaStore you should query the MediaStore for pictures with RELATIVE_PATH "Pictures/Office Lens". You willl get a cursor/list with ids/uries for all the imagefiles.

Comment: Hi @blackapps, many thank to your answer.
Reverting my code, and check it again in order to better describe the exceptions and answer to your questions, I found where I took the wrong way.
When I changed the implementation to process images captured from the "ActionImageCapture" intent, switching from filepath to URI for the FileProvider, I wanted to manage also images from OfficeLens via URI, that I wasn't able to retrieve.

Comment: When I check till Android version the FilePath works, in order to answer your question, I discover that it's still working indeed!

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media/1563");

InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

Answer (score 0):

The GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory is still working targeting Android 10 and Android 11 to retrieve the path for Images/xyz.

Furthermore, it's still possible to get a bitmap like this:

```
public static Bitmap LoadBitmap(this string filePath)
{
  var options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

  options.InJustDecodeBounds = false;

  return BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(fileName, options);
}
```

where filePath are read from the result of GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory with the method ListFiles():

```
var TmpDir = new Java.IO.File(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures), "xyz");

foreach (var I in TmpDir.ListFiles())
{
  if (I.IsFile == true)
  {
    var Bmp = LoadBitmap(I.Path);
  }
}
```

Thanks to @blackapps for the hits!